# Elasticsearch not showing running log in python

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am new in Elasticsearch. I have a running Elasticsearch instance in cloud and accessing it via python, i want to see running logs which has a field - "type"- "filebeat". I have following lines of code:

```
import elasticsearch
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
import elasticsearch.helpers

# Creating the client instance
es = Elasticsearch(
    cloud_id=CLOUD_ID,
    basic_auth=("elastic", ELASTIC_PASSWORD)
)

# Successful response!
print(es.info())
ES_INDEX = <my index>
ES_TYPE="filebeat"
results_gen = elasticsearch.helpers.scan(
    es,
    query={"query": {"match_all": {}}},
    index=ES_INDEX)

results = list(results_gen)
print(results)
```

The output shows the instance details and 4407 logs in result (obviously all logs). My question is how to obtain running logs and how to modify the query to show only logs with "type"-"filebeat"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do some filtering in your query.

```py
results_gen = elasticsearch.helpers.scan(
    es,
    query={"query": {"match_all": {}}},
    index=ES_INDEX)
```

In here, you are using `match_all`. This will return all data on your index.

Here is a query sample above. `term` query will filter the data according to `type: filebeat`.

```py
results_gen = elasticsearch.helpers.scan(
    es,
    query={"query": {"term": {"type": "filebeat"}}},
    index=ES_INDEX)
```

Also, you can check the documentation for more.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html

Comment: Thank you. Got the idea very well. Built the json, passed into query field and now its giving me exact entries. Any idea how to get running logs?

Comment: What does it mean exactly with "running logs"?

Comment: I want a loop or something so that I can read new logs that the instance generates. Right now it generates a log entry in every 5 seconds. But my python code reads the recent 4407 logs and stops.

Comment: You need to build a loop that should work with a timeout. For example, you can say every 5 seconds; you need to the user [search_after](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/paginate-search-results.html#search-after).